# How to delay the hover?

Tags: html, css

```css
   .proposal p{
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #494949;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      display: -webkit-box;
      line-height: 20px;
      max-height: 100px;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    
    }
    
    .proposal p:hover{
      overflow: visible;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="proposal">
                    <strong>Proposal</strong>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat voluptatibus ullam illum et aperiam nostrum inventore ad maxime mollitia ducimus sequi, veniam at in qui, quo asperiores odio, ut pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, laborum, commodi. Accusantium repellat facilis omnis consequatur, rerum porro mollitia</p>
                  </div>
```

here's the HTML and CSS for the text block, I want to slow down the hover effect through some css3 animation how can it be done.?

Comment: Overflow is hidden or visible, it can't be animated, i would say... Also, your current CSS works only in Chrome...

Comment: @sinisake what do i do to support other browsers ?